# How to pass dictionary or list or custom objects from feature file

Tags: python-2.7, python-behave

If a method takes dictionary as parameter, how to pass it. Do we need to construct the dictionary from values present in  feature file and pass internally to the method. Is there any direct way we can pass objects?

Comment: If understood your question, and I hope I miss understood it, do you mean to do something like that?: 
def foo(bar):
     print bar     

foo({"a":1, "b":2, "c": {"d":4}})
{'a': 1, 'c': {'d': 4}, 'b': 2}

Comment: Yes correct. so bar is dict object

Comment: In python, you can pass as argument to a method whatever you want.

Comment: pretty confused. so what is your question about 'python-behave'? Do you mean that when behave is executing with your feature file, you wanna some steps to be run with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't pass objects in features, but you can send text and tables in the feature file. The text you send can be exploited to send JSON string of your dict/lists and further create objects using that data in step definition.